# Swapping two variable using pointers

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I am trying to write a swap function using pointer(specially a void pointer)by-reference, but my code is not working. Here is my code:

```
void swap(void *p1,void *p2) 
{
    int temp;   
    temp=*((int*)p2);
    p2=p1; 
    p1=&temp;
}

int main() 
{
    int i=4;
    int j=5; 
    cout<<i<<j<<endl;
    swap(&i,&j); 
    cout<<i<<j<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is broken in a lot of ways, but the most important issue (IMO) is assigning `p1`,`p2` with values, while you actually need to assign the address they address to. This is not the only issue, just the most important IMO.

Comment: Do they need to pass the pointers by reference ?

Comment: Since you are swaping ints, you needn't pass the function parameters as voids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code does not work because you are not dereferencing your pointers on assignments. It should be

```
*((int*)p2)=*((int*)p1);
*((int*)p1)=temp;
```

Note that you are making an assumption that `void*` points to an `int`, which is obviously not always the case. Essentially, you might as well replace `void*` with `int*`, and get rid of the casts.

A more general case of the API should look like this:

```
void swap(void *p1,void *p2, size_t sz)
```

Internally, the API should allocate a buffer of size `sz`, make a `memcpy` into it, and then make a swap, again using `memcpy`.

Comment: This is assuming the types are trivially copyable-.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Right -- essentially, this amounts to a trivial swap of memory contents in non-overlapping regions.

Answer (score 2):

In the body of the function, you're swapping the values of `p1` and `p2`; you don't want to do that.  You want to swap the values of what `p1` and `p2` *point to*:

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
  int tmp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = tmp;
}
```

I know you wanted to use `void *` for your arguments.  Don't.  You'd have to cast them to the appropriate target type to perform the assignments anyway:

```
int tmp = *(int *) p1;
*(int *) p1 = *(int *) p2;
*(int *) p2 = tmp;
```

Yuck.  You're not saving yourself anything by making the arguments `void *`.

Since you're obviously writing C++, you can make the function generic by using a template:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T *p1, T *p2)
{
  T tmp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = tmp;
}
```

Even better, use a template and *references*, so you're not dealing with pointers at all:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T &p1, T &p2)
{
  T tmp = p1;
  p1 = p2;
  p2 = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Wait a minute - haven't I seen that last function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying copies of pointers, not their content.
You should do something like this (just showing you the idea, this would not work without casts and it would still not be a good idea with):

```
temp = *p2
*p2 = *p1;
*p1 = temp;
```

You are going to need pointers to pointers if you want to swap your pointers:

```
void swap(void** ptr1, void** ptr2);
```

or references to pointers:

```
void swap(void*& ptr1, void*& ptr2);
```

Or since you're obviously using C++, you could use references and templates to swap any type of data. But are you sure you understood all the basics of the language?

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

using memory functions

```
void swap (void *vp1, void *vp2, const int size) {
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
memcpy(buffer, vp1, size);
memcpy(vp1, vp2, size);
memcpy(vp2, buffer, size);
free(buffer);
}

int main()
{
int a = 10, b = 20;
printf("%d %d"a,b);
swap(&a, &b, sizeof(int));
printf("%d %d"a,b);

}

Output is:

10 , 20
20 , 10
```

if we dont know data type then we use void.

Comment: Actually, in C++ we use `template <typename T>` when we don't know the type yet. The compiler will know, use the real type `T` and then check for errors. That's why we have `template <typename T> std::swap(T&, T&)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap( void *a, void *b ) {
  int tmp = *( ( int* )a );
  *( ( int* )a ) = *( ( int* )b );
  *( ( int* )b ) = tmp;
}

int main() {
  int a, b;
  cin >> a >> b;
  swap( &a, &b );
  cout << a << " " << b;
  return 0;
}
```

Before you dereference the pointers a and b, you must first convert them to `int*`. After that, you just perform the swapping.

*Note:* You needn't pass `void*` as parameter. If you pass `int*`s, it will be also correct (and more readable).

*Note[2]:* Since you are programming in C++ you could use instead of pointers references.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Swap(int **ptr1, int **ptr2){
    // Swapping the contents of p1 and p2 in the driver function
    int *temp;
    temp = *ptr1;                   
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
    // Swapping the contents of x and y in the driver function
    int temp;
    temp = **ptr1;                  
    **ptr1 = **ptr2;
    **ptr2 = temp;
}

int main(){
    int x = 10, y = 15;
    int *p1 = nullptr;
    p1 = &x;
    int *p2 = nullptr;
    p2 = &y;
    cout << x << ' ' << y << endl;
    cout << *p1 << ' ' << *p2 << endl;
    Swap(&p1,&p2);
    cout << x << ' ' << y << endl;
    cout << *p1 << ' ' << *p2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the contents of p1 and p2 in the driver function 
code does not work. This is probably because you are trying to swap the memory address starting location and the os restricts that. ??
The memory functions however does the job.

Comment: This hardly help OP. Can you provide an example of how the "memory functions" work?